# React Native: How to conditionally render a value returned from a function that calls Firebase function?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-firebase

In my React Native app, I have the following function that returns a value from Firebase:

```
const func = () => {
  const a = useFirestoreCollection(
    userRepository
      .getRef()
      .collection('collection1')
      .doc('doc1')
  )
  return a.name;
}
```

and then the component looks like this:

```
return (
  <Text>
    {func()}
  </Text>
)
```

The problem is, I want to render it conditionally, like this:

```
return (
  <Text>
    {func() ? func() : "backup"}
  </Text>
)
```

but this throws the error `Rendered more hooks than during the previous render`.

How can I achieve this conditional render?

Comment: What would you do here instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is already breaking the rules of hooks by calling `useFirestoreCollection` in a nested function so the use case isn't valid. Call `useFirestoreCollection` as a hook normally and check the returned value.

Example:

```
const a = useFirestoreCollection(
  userRepository
    .getRef()
    .collection('collection1')
    .doc('doc1')
);

...

return (
  <Text>
    {a?.name || "backup"}
  </Text>
);
```